Search Data Through excel User Form in Excel with multiple criteria

Private Sub TextBox2_AfterUpdate()
  Dim Here As Range
  Dim c, d As Long
  c = TextBox1.Value
  d = TextBox2.Value
  Set Here = Sheet1.Range("A:B").Find("c", "d", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
  If Here Is Nothing Then
    'TextBox2.Value = ""
    TextBox3.Value = ""
    TextBox4.Value = ""
  Else
    'TextBox2.Value = Here.Offset(, 1)
    TextBox3.Value = Here.Offset(, 2)
    TextBox4.Value = Here.Offset(, 3)
  End If
End Sub

above coding is for below table
      A         B       C       D
     ID       MONTH    NAME  PAYMENT
1   DO-2768    JAN      A       5
2   DO-2535    MAR      B       10
3   EO-6754    OCT      C       12
4   ER-9087    FEB      D      158
5   DO-2535    APR      B     2563
6   DO-6754    DEC      E     4587
7   ER-9087    MAR      D      102
8   DO-2535    MAY      B     3625
9
10





A
B
C
D





ID
MONTH
NAME
PAYMENT


1
DO-2768
JAN
A
5


2
DO-2535
MAR
B
10


3
EO-6754
OCT
C
12


4
ER-9087
FEB
D
158


5
DO-2535
APR
B
2563


6
DO-6754
DEC
E
4587


7
ER-9087
MAR
D
102


8
DO-2535
MAY
B
3625


9






10







Regards
SAM

Post few sample data as text table. Show your current code then explain what you are trying to do.

Pls. apply formatting options in the future.

Your FIND syntax is wrong - it's looking for the value "c" (as in the letter c, not the variable c).  The "d" should be a cell reference not the letter "d".  I take it Textbox1 will have an ID value, and TextBox2 will have a month name?

I'd search for the ID and if that's found check each occurrence to see if the correct month is next to it.
Private Sub TextBox2_AfterUpdate()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
        Dim Found As Boolean

        'Find last row containing data based on column A.
        Dim LastRow As Long
        LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        
        'Search for an instance of the ID.
        Dim Here As Range
        Set Here = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, 1)).Find(What:=Me.TextBox1.Value, _
                                                                 After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                                                                 LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                                                 LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                                                 SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                                                 SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                                                 MatchCase:=False)
                                                                 
        'If the ID has been found then search for all instances of ID
        'and check the next column for the month.
        If Not Here Is Nothing Then
            Dim FirstAdd As String
            FirstAdd = Here.Address
            Do
                'If the month is also found then set the Found marker to true and exit the loop.
                If Here.Offset(, 1) = Me.TextBox2.Value Then
                    Found = True
                    Exit Do
                End If
                Set Here = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, 1)).FindNext(Here)
            Loop While Here.Address <> FirstAdd
        End If
    
    End With
    
    'Populate the text boxes based on the Found boolean marker.
    If Found Then
        TextBox3.Value = Here.Offset(, 2)
        TextBox4.Value = Here.Offset(, 3)
    Else
        TextBox3.Value = ""
        TextBox4.Value = ""
    End If

End Sub  

Further reading:
Range.Find method
With statement
